# ReactJS - Dynamic Routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have these components. I want to turn every `<House/>` into a dynamic url. For example, when accessing in the browser, `http://localhost:3000/houses/house/1` 
I want to appear the House 1.

The other things in the application are working fine. I just want to solve this problem of implementing dynamic routes.

**Router Component**

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'

import App from './App'   
import Houses from './Houses'    

export default props => (
  <Router>
    <Route exact path='/' render={() => <App />} >       
      <Route exact path='/houses' render={() => <Houses />} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
)
```

**Houses Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import House from './House'

var data = require('./db.json');

class Houses extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentHouse: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({    
      currentHouse: data[0]    
    })
  }

  render() {
    const {currentHouse} =  this.state;           
    return (
      <div className="content house">     
        <ul>
        {currentHouse.photos && currentHouse.photos.map((photo, index) => {
          return(
           <House photo={photo} key={index}/>
          )
        })}
      </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Houses
```

**House Component**

```
import React from 'react';

function House(prop) {
  return (
    <li><img src={`/images/${prop.photo}`}/></li>
  );
}

export default House;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<Route exact path='/houses/:id' render={(props) => <House {...props} />} />
```

and inside House component retrieve the id:

```
prop.match.params.id
```

Ref: https://scotch.io/courses/using-react-router-4/route-params

Comment: About `prop.match.params.id` Where do I set this up? in `this.state`?

Comment: If you return House component, you will find it in props passed to the component itself, take a look at my link

Comment: Ok, I'll do as you indicated.

Comment: @claudiobitar `prop.match.params.id` is a Route prop that you pass to the House component in the Route `render()` function as seen in this answer.